# Is it possible to preload Sqlite DB on Palm Pre?

Tags: database, sqlite, webos

I have a Palm Pre app that has a large(ish) database. I would like to transfer the database directly to the phone rather than having the app create the database.

What I tried is to create a sqlite file on the PC using a simple python script, then have the app create an empty extended db in the media/internal folders, then copy the PC file over the one created on the phone. However I get an error when trying to read the file: "database disk image is malformed".

Has anyone succeeded in doing something like this?

**Edit**: Now that my original idea is actually not possible my question becomes: what is the best way to initialize an application DB with a lot of data without duplicating it (now I have an array with info and the first time the app is run it creates and fills the database). The solution to use a hybrid application is too much for me now, I need a simple and quick solution.

The alternative would probably be to connect to a 'web service' and download the data to the application.

Comment: I haven't, but I should point out that you shouldn't really rely on this working.  It might, but the point of creating a database from a sql dump is to avoid just the kind of problems you're running into.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access a preloaded SQLite database directly from your JavaScript code -- while WebKit is using SQLite internally, it needs to associate the database with its own data structures and manage some constraints.

You could write a hybrid application where your C/C++ code just acted as a server for accessing the included data file.  You can use that static version of SQLite in your hybrid app to get access to that data and send it over the IPC system to JS.  That model is similar to how Quickfoffice on the device uses a hybrid to parse MS Word documents and send their representation to their JS app that shows them using WebKit's rendering engine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to let the app create a base sqlite file, then download that to your desktop in order to add the bulk data? You should probably close the app before sending it back to the phone. If it's a built-in app like calendar, you might have issues because a background process might still be accessing the db. Maybe a reboot after uploading will solve it.

Comment: That's what I originally tried and I couldn't open the phone generated database on the computer. It gave me some 'malformed' error